# Get default language of the device from inside an app in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

Is there any method allow us to get the default language of the tablet in order to use it in an application using c# windows 8.1

Comment: how about CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; or CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;` in order to get the current culture info. in it will be the language.

for example :

```
currentCulture.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName
```

please [read more on CultureInfo here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)